# How can I retain FileDialog Input value, even if user selects Cancel? (ASP.Net / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Apparently, If you upload a file to the web with the FileDialog and then the user re-opens the file dialog and clicks cancel, any prior selected file is not longer retained as an input/file value.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p333qb1d/8/) of some WIP code, You can see that I though about storing the currently selected file in a variable to re-attach as the input file if the user selects cancel, but apparently that doesnt work.

Since I have to accompany the fiddle link with code, here is a snippet of some of the JS

```
   var currentlySelectedFile = $("#AttachmentUpLoad_FileUpload")[0].files[0] ; 

$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function () {
    var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');

        if(numFiles > 0){
                input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
        }
        else{
       /*  $("#AttachmentUpLoad_FileUpload").[0].files[0]  =(currentlySelectedFile); */
            return;
        }

});
```

How do you actually get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filesSaved = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputfile').on('change', function() {
        if (this.files.length > 0) {
            filesSaved = this.files;
        }
    });
});
```

You start you page with the fileSaved object blank.  On everytime the users select a file, you set the files selected to the fileSaved object.

So when the user cancels, you still have the fileSaved object to process.